# haproxy exclude a url from https redirection

Tags: haproxy

I am beginner with haproxy and trying to do same basic redirection with haproxy

I have 2 sites

1. www.test.com -> want to this to be redirected to https
2. www.test.com/helpsub -> Should not redirect to https and remain on http

Is this possible ?

Best Regards,

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the 1.5 version of HAProxy.

To redirect to https can be done via the `redirect scheme` directive. This directive has an optional conditions list, so you could set up an ACL for this purpose.

For instance to set up an acl to match the /helpsub path, you could have:

```
acl helpsub path_beg /helpsub
```

And to then do the redirect to https for everything, except the helpsub (and of course only when the connection is not yet via ssl) you could have:

```
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc } !helpsub
```

The `!` sign means `not matching`, so basically this reads as:

> redirect the request to the https scheme, if you are not on an ssl
> connection and the path does not start with /helpsub.

[Reference.](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#4.2-redirect%20scheme)

Comment: Hi I used this  acl folder path_dir -i /helpsub 

redirect scheme https code 301 if !folder !{ ssl_fc }

Comment: It seems to be working

Comment: work fine :) good work